# $\phi$ invariant Borel probability measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, dynamical-systems

Given $X$ and  $\phi:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$

$\phi(x)= \begin{cases} \frac{1}{2}x & x\neq0\\ 1&x=0\end{cases}$

I've to show that there can't be a Borel-probability measure $\mu$ which is $\phi$ invariant (i.e. $\mu(\phi^{-1}(A))=\mu(A)$ $\forall A\in \mathcal{B}(X)$)

---

My first idea was proving it by contradiction. But without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose such probability measure $P$ on $[0, 1]$ exists. Suppose $F(x)$ is its CDF. By our supposition:

$F(x) = \begin{cases}
    1 - P(\{0\} )  & \quad x > \frac{1}{2}\\
    F(2x) - P(\{0\})  & \quad x \leq \frac{1}{2}
  \end{cases}$

If $P(\{0\}) > 0$, then $\exists x > 0 \text{ such that } F(x) < 0$, which is impossible.

If $P(\{0\}) = 0$, then $\forall x > 0 \text{ } F(x) = 1$, which is also impossible.

Thus we receive a contradiction.

Comment: thanks ! But can you explain how you build $F(x)$ ? I hoped we could find a contradiction by showing $\mu(\phi^{-1}(A))\neq\mu(A)$ or by violating the definition of a measure  for example the $\sigma $- additivity. (I'm doing  course about  dynamical systems. We just talked about a few results in measure theory. We didn't use Cumulative distribution function)

Comment: @ThomasMuller, in this case $F(x) = P([0, x])$. To show the contradiction we use facts, that $F(x)$ is always greater than zero (which is obvious), and that it is right-continuous (which is easily implied by $\sigma$-additivity of P).

Comment: I'm getting the idea. Can you say a few words to $P(\{0\})=0$ and where we used the $\phi$- invariance ?

Comment: @ThomasMuller, $\phi$ - invariance was used in the statement  $F(x) = P([0, x]) = P(\phi^{-1}([0, x])) = \begin{cases}
    1 - P(\{0\} )  & \quad x > \frac{1}{2}\\
    F(2x) - P(\{0\})  & \quad x \leq \frac{1}{2}
  \end{cases}$

Comment: @ThomasMuller, if $P({0}) = 0$, then $F(x) = \begin{cases}
    1   & \quad x > \frac{1}{2}\\
    F(2x)  & \quad x \leq \frac{1}{2}
  \end{cases}$, which results in $F(x) = \begin{cases}
    1   & \quad x > 0\\
    0  & \quad x = 0
  \end{cases}$, and this function is definitely not right-continuous.

Comment: Great answer ! Thanks a lot